# Passing quotes "do shell script" in AppleScript... Again

Tags: applescript

I have the following line in AppleScript

```
set msgDate to (current date) as string
set removalString to "\"rm -f ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.playlister.\"" as string    
do shell script "echo do shell script " & removalString & msgDate & ".plist" & ">> ~/Library/Playlister/" & msgDate & ".applescript"
```

What I'm trying to do, yet again, is pass the string

```
do shell script "rm -f ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.playlister.whateverthedatestampis.plist"
```

*with* the quotes in the correct place. I'm moving stuff around quite a bit in a blind attempt to get the quotes right, and I've almost gotten it, but not quite.

Any insight or assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
set msgDate to (current date) as text
set removalString to "rm -f ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.playlister."

do shell script "echo do shell script \\\"" & removalString & msgDate & ".plist\\\"" & " >> ~/Library/Playlister/" & quoted form of msgDate & ".applescript"
```

Comment: Yes. I. Freaking. Am. Thanks again @adayzdone. Really appreciate the expertise. :-)